# Unable to adding Aurora data source to an Amplify app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli

It's probably something simple related to IAM set up that I'm missing, but I can't figure out where it needs to be done. I have an Amplify application in reactjs as the client. I have already created my RDS database and trying to add that database as the data source with `amplify api add-graphql-datasource` command. But it gives me the following error message:

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/us-east-1_1EGhMm2jL_Full-access/amplifyadmin is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBClusters on resource: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:XXX:cluster:*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to find the auto-generated role `us-east-1_1EGhMm2jL_Full-access` and assign following policies to it: `AmazonRDSDataFullAccess`, `SecretsManagerReadWrite`, `AmazonRDSFullAccess`.